# Is it possible to deploy an application using cassandra database on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, cassandra

I recently got a trial version of Windows Azure and wanted to know if there is any way I can deploy an application using Cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you run Cassandra as a worker role in Azure. Then, you can mount an Azure drive when a worker starts up and unmount when it shuts down.

This provides some insight re: how to use Cassandra on Azure: http://things.smarx.com/#Run Cassandra

Some help w/ Azure drives: http://azurescope.cloudapp.net/CodeSamples/cs/792ce345-256b-4230-a62f-903f79c63a67/

This should not limit your scalability at all. Just spin up another Cassandra instance whenever processing throughput or contiguous storage become an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak specifically to Cassandra working or not in Azure unfortuantly. That's likely a question for that product's development team.

But the challenge you'll face with this, mySQL, or any other role hosted database is persistence. Azure Roles are in and of themselves not persistent so whatever back end store Cassandra is using would need to be placed onto soemthing like an Azure Drive (which is persisted to Azure Blob Storage). However, this would limit the scalability of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). AppHarbor is a .Net PaaS built on top of Amazon. It gives users the portability and infrastructure of Amazon and they provide a number of the rich services that Azure offers such as background tasks & load balancing plus some that it doesn't like 3rd party add-ons, dead-simple deployment and more. They already have add-ons for CouchDB, MongoDB and Redis if Cassandra got high enough on the requested features I'm sure they could set it up.